# check-manifest fails after upgrading setuptools_scm from 6.0.1 to 6.3.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, setuptools-scm

I have been using `setuptools-scm` version `6.0.1` for my [python project](https://github.com/zobayer1/logging-extras). The project also uses `check-manifest` with a pre-commit hook. Ever since I upgraded `setuptools-scm` to 6.3.1, the check-manifest hook has been failing with the following error that looks like it wasn't able to determine the correct version string from sdist packaging.

```sh
ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke build_sdist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zobayer/.cache/pre-commit/repoijtr5gb3/py_env-python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/zobayer/.cache/pre-commit/repoijtr5gb3/py_env-python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 331, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/home/zobayer/.cache/pre-commit/repoijtr5gb3/py_env-python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 301, in build_sdist
    return backend.build_sdist(sdist_directory, config_settings)
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 225, in build_sdist
    return self._build_with_temp_dir(['sdist', '--formats', 'gztar'],
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 207, in _build_with_temp_dir
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 453, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 292, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 831, in finalize_options
    ep(self)
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools_scm/integration.py", line 94, in infer_version
    dist.metadata.version = _get_version(config)
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 185, in _get_version
    dump_version(
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 90, in dump_version
    parsed_version = Version(version)
  File "/tmp/build-env-nswqxife/lib/python3.8/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 266, in __init__
    raise InvalidVersion(f"Invalid version: '{version}'")
packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: 'extras-0.3.0.dev3+g4d323bc.d20210909'
```

It is interesting to see that the reported version string is completely wrong (`extras-0.3.0.dev3+g4d323bc.d20210909`). Part of the library name seems to be getting added with the version string.

However, it still runs fine with `6.0.1`, so downgrading is an option. But I would like to know how to make them work together. I have looked into some other threads suggesting the use of a weak flag or setting `SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION=0.0`, but none of the approaches worked. I am not sure why it is getting `extras` as part of the version string. Here's my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=3.4"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
write_to = "logging_/version.py"
write_to_template = "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n\n__version__ = '{version}'\n"
version_scheme = "release-branch-semver"

[tool.check-manifest]
ignore = ["logging_/version.py"]

[tool.black]
line-length = 120
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.eggs
  | \.git
  | \.pytest_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | build
  | dist
)/
'''
```

**Update**: I have added [an issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/issues/630) in the `setuptools-scm` project regarding this.

**Update**: This was indeed a bug in the check-manifest library. Go to  [reported issue](https://github.com/mgedmin/check-manifest/issues/145) and a [possible fix](https://github.com/mgedmin/check-manifest/pull/146).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue caused due to a bug in the check-manifest library where the sdist filenames containing dashes were being parsed incorrectly when trying to extract the version string.

Possible solutions:

1. Wait for the maintainers to provide a fix,
2. Remove check-manifest dependency from pre-commit or build dependencies.
3. Rename python library removing the dash, e.g. `logging-extras` to `logging_extras` in setup.py file.

EDIT

[My PR got accepted, and the fix is released with 0.47](https://github.com/mgedmin/check-manifest/issues/145#issuecomment-924749626)